# Firefox Doubt in LAN

Tags: local-area-network, firefox

Is there an option in fire fox to run it via LAN???

After connecting to other user by SSH,

and if type

```
firefox
```

on the command prompt,

will it pop up other user's fire fox window?

and I'm using

```
Fedora 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, but this is not specific to Firefox.

This is called X11 Forwarding.

Ensure that the server's config file (assuming openssh) has this directive :

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

You can then connect doing `ssh -X user@server` and launch firefox from the terminal, or even `ssh -X user@server firefox`

Comment: How could i locate the X11Forwarding ????

Comment: I meant the location of that file??? I'm using fedora 13 as the server and hosts

Comment: I'd say `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. This is where it is on debian...

Comment: Thank you for the help.

It shows up firefox,But when firefox run at other system,it shows up

"Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system."  How could i skip this?

Comment: @PeaceLover This is nothing to "skip". This is a message to follow.